# javascript scroll position index automatisation

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working but I had to enter every case manually, now I'm trying to optimize it to make it work in any situation.
But I don't understand the best way to do it

The goal of it is to know where I am in the page and do specific stuff when current index have a specific value:

here's my JS code :

```
var sections = $('.section'),
scroll,

offset = [],

currentIndex = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  offset.push(sections[i].offsetTop)
}



// console.log(offset) -> [0, 807, 1704, 2601, 3498, 4395]



window.onscroll = function(){
  scroll = window.scrollY
  if(scroll > offset[0] && scroll < offset[1]){
    currentIndex = 1
    console.log(currentIndex)
  }
  if(scroll > offset[1] && scroll < offset[2]){
    currentIndex = 2
    console.log(currentIndex)
  }
  if(scroll > offset[2] && scroll < offset[3]){
    currentIndex = 3
    console.log(currentIndex)
  }
  if(scroll > offset[3] && scroll < offset[4]){
    currentIndex = 4
    console.log(currentIndex)
  }
  if(scroll > offset[4] && scroll < offset[5]){
    currentIndex = 5
    console.log(currentIndex)
  }
  if(scroll >= offset[5]){
    currentIndex = 6
    console.log(currentIndex);
  }
}
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<header class="section header"></header>
<section class="section sectionWhite"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<section class="section sectionWhite"></section>
<section class="section"></section>
<footer class="section header"></footer>
```

any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: Share your HTML as well.

Comment: I added the HTML ;)

Comment: You may use javascript Array.find function with element, index and self array and test the current item and the next one. You may need to take care of the special case when the element in the array is the last one. The idea is something like `offset.find(function(value, index, self) {return (value < scroll < self[index + 1])}` edit: you may use findIndex instead of find, it would give you the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question to a friend and his answer is really good, for those who also have the same problem as I have:

```
function getOffsetIndex(value,offsetArray){

  for(var i = offsetArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(value >= offsetArray[i]){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

window.onscroll = function(){
  scroll = window.scrollY
  var offsetIndex = getOffsetIndex(scroll,offset);
  console.log(offsetIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you want to get away from manually writing all the cases, something like this might be of your interest. Below approach would work for any length of your offset array.

```
    window.scroll = function() {
    scroll = window.scrollY;
    arrayLength = offset.length; // array length is 6 in your case
    if(scroll >= offset[arrayLength-1]){
        currentIndex = arrayLength; // the currentIndex value would be 6 in your case
        console.log(currentIndex);
    }else{
        for (i=0; i< offset.length-2; i++){
            if(scroll > offset[i] && scroll < offset[i+1]){
                currentIndex = i+1; // the currentIndex value would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in your case
                console.log(currentIndex);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer!
It works, but it bypass the before last currentIndex: 
output is => 1,2,3,4,6

Comment: I think I fixed it :
the for loop in the else, i was compared to offset.length-2 if I change it to offset.length-1 it works